# JOINs being done in weird order; messing up ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by, query-optimization, explain

Let's say I have three tables - users, servers and payments. Each user can have multiple servers and each server can have multiple payments. Let's also say I wanted to find the most recent payments and get info about the servers / customers those payments are attached to. Here's a query that could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM payments p
JOIN customers c ON p.custID = c.custID
JOIN servers s ON s.serverID = p.serverID
WHERE c.hold = 0
    AND c.archive = 0
ORDER BY p.paymentID DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The problem is that when I run EXPLAIN on this query I get this:

```
id   select_type   table   type   possible_keys            key                key_len   ref                 rows     Extra
1    SIMPLE        c       ref    PRIMARY,hold_archive     hold_archive       3         const,const         28728    Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1    SIMPLE        p       ref    custID                   custID             5         customers.custID    3        Using where
1    SIMPLE        s       eq_ref PRIMARY                  PRIMARY            4         payments.serverID   1        Using index
```

The problem is that the query takes a while to run. If I remove the ORDER BY it becomes 10x as fast. But I need the ORDER BY. Here's the EXPLAIN when I remove the ORDER BY:

```
id   select_type   table   type   possible_keys            key                key_len   ref                 rows     Extra
1    SIMPLE        c       ref    PRIMARY,hold_archive     hold_archive       3         const,const         28728    Using where; Using index
1    SIMPLE        p       ref    custID                   custID             5         customers.custID    3        Using where
1    SIMPLE        s       eq_ref PRIMARY                  PRIMARY            4         payments.serverID   1        Using index
```

So the big difference here is that "Using temporary" and "Using filesort" are missing from the Extra column.

It seems like the reason, in this case, is that the column I'm doing the ORDER BY on isn't the first column in the EXPLAIN.

Another observation. If I remove one of the WHERE clauses (whilst keeping the ORDER BY) it speeds up similarily, but I need both WHERE's. Here's an example EXPLAIN of that:

```
id   select_type   table   type   possible_keys            key                key_len   ref                 rows     Extra
1    SIMPLE        p       index  custID,serverID          PRIMARY            4         NULL                10       Using where
1    SIMPLE        c       eq_ref PRIMARY,hold_archive     PRIMARY            4         payments.custID     1        Using where
1    SIMPLE        s       eq_ref PRIMARY                  PRIMARY            4         payments.serverID   1        Using index
```

Here the ORDER BY column /is/ being done on the first column of the EXPLAIN. But why is MySQL re-arranging the order the tables are JOINed in and how can I make it so it doesn't do that? You can force indexes in MySQL but it doesn't seem like that'd help..

Any ideas?

Comment: With questions like this, you also need to provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables

Comment: Quick guess: if there is no `ORDER BY` clause, then the server returns you literately the first 10 records that match the criteria and stops processing once it reaches that number. It probably starts with the `customer` table because there is a filter on that one and then looks for related `payments` and later on `servers` that match. Works quite well. However, when you do add the `ORDER BY` then it will first need to make a list of *all* the matching records (`c`=>`p`=>`s`), sort those on the `paymentID` and then pick the first 10 from that list starting with the 'lowest' one.

Answer (score 1):

10x faster -- It can find "any 10 rows" a lot faster than "find all possible rows, sort them, then deliver 10".

Having `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` hit different columns is hard to optimize.

What percentage of payments have `hold=0 and archive=0`?  It sounds like a small percentage?  How many rows in each table?

Does anything else need `INDEX(hold, archive)`?  If not, get rid of it.  It seems to be only causing trouble here.

If `hold=0 and archive=0` is common, then you would prefer the execution to go like your 3rd `EXPLAIN` -- that is scan `payments` in descending order.  With most of them matching the `WHERE`, it will *usually*` need to hit not much more than 10 rows before finding 10 matching rows.

Another solution (other than getting rid of the index) is to change `JOIN` to `STRAIGHT_JOIN` in the query.  This tells the Optimizer that you know better, and `payments` should be scanned first, `customers` second.  That works well if my previous paragraph applies.

But the query will screw up (by being slow) if, say, you look for `archive=1`.